# Статический метод для проверки наличия интернет соединения

Tags: java, android

```
public boolean isOnline() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo nInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (nInfo != null && nInfo.isConnected()) {
                return true; // есть соединение
            }
            else {
                return false; // нет соединения
            }

      }
```

Представленный выше метод нельзя объявить как статический, так как в `getSystemService` имеется не статический контекст.
И еще метод возвращает Истину даже , если вайвай подключен , но интернета нет или если  передача данных включена, но интернет не оплачен. Есть ли другой готовый метод ?  Можно попытаться самому проверить пинг к гуглу например и если нет, то сделать вывод что интернет отключен, но тут может и временный сбой помешать.

Comment: Чтобы метод был статическим, отдайте ему статический контекст. Например, `Application`.

Comment: А узнать фактический статус интернета можно только пингом (или обращением к сайту). Может быть такое, что Wi-Fi есть, а шнура — нет.

Comment: Rostislav Dugin, заменил context на Application. продолжает статический контекст просить

Comment: [Static way to get 'Context' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5114361)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевод этого ответа — [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection):

---

Метод проверяет, подключено ли устрой к интернету и возвращает `true`, если подключено.

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
 }
```

В манифесте должны быть эти разрешения:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

А этот метод проверяет фактический доступ к сети (можно ли зайти на сайт, например):

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
        try {
            //You can replace it with your name
            InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
            return !ipAddr.equals("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null; что значит эта строка если перевести на человеческий? Вернуть что?

Comment: @Turalllb, исходники посмотрите, документацию почитайте. Скорее всего, если интернет активный (Android может куда-то достучаться), возвращается какое-то значение, а если не может, возвращается `null`.

Comment: Ну да, точно.  А вот передав Application  вместо context метод статическим объявить не получается. Есть еще какие то предложения?

Comment: Дело в том что сам метод getSystemService сам не статический метод.

Comment: @Turalllb, это метод контекста. Попробуйте, например, `Application.getContext().getSystemService`.

Comment: Rostislav Dugin, в классе extends AppCompatActivity я пишу  Application и у него нет вообще никаких методов.. getContext() отсутствует

Comment: @Turalllb, a... Забыл. Создайте класс `Application`, который наследуется от `Application`, а потом добавьте ему метод `.getInstance()`. Подробнее о этих классах читайте в гугле, их еще и в манифесте нужно объявить.